# Create multiple columns using SAS macros

Tags: sas, multiple-columns, sas-macro, do-loops

I have a column named STRATA in my dataset named plot.

Plot

```
Strata
------
0 
1
3  ****the values are in repeats********
```

I would like to create multiple category columns such as `YAS YES YCS SEP` in the dataset based on the unique input of these unique (strata) values.

- For strata values `0 1 3`, as above, then columns to be created are
   `YAS0 YES0 YCS0 SEP0 YAS1 YES1 YCS1 SEP1 YAS3 YES3 YCS3 SEP3`.
- For strata value `2 3 5` then
  `YAS2 YES2 YCS2 SEP2 YAS3 YES3 YCS3 SEP3 YAS5 YES5 YCS5 SEP5`.

How to achieve this in the form of macro, please guide ?

Comment: If you want to create variable names from data use PROC TRANSPOSE with the ID statement.  Do you have actual data you want to put into these variables?

Comment: I have used proc transpose and by the id variable I can pass only 1 variable at a time. let me know if this can be achieved through macro with a do loop .

Comment: Why can't you use more one variable in the ID statement? Is your data not structured right?

Answer (score 0):

You are cross joining data with, I presume, a list of variables.   This disparate arrangement can be processed in a macro that uses `doSubL` function to submit a complex processing for macro variable assignment in a non-step context.

The doSubL code creates a table from the list and use SQL to cross join that with the strata.

Example:

```
data have;
input strata @@; datalines;
0   1   3
;

%macro strataed_vars (data=, var=);

  %local rc result;

  %let rc = %sysfunc(dosubl(%str(

    * options nonotes; /* uncomment to declutter the log */

    data _names(keep=var);
      list = "&var";
      do _n_ = 1 to countw(list);
        var = scan (list, _n_);
        output;
      end;
    run;

    proc sql noprint;
      select cats(var,strata)
      into :result separated by ' '
      from &data cross join _names
      ;
      drop table _names;
  )));

  &result   /* emit result as source code */
%mend;

%put %strataed_vars (data=have, var=YAS YES YCS SEP);
```

Log:

```
392  %mend;
393
NOTE: The data set WORK._NAMES has 4 observations and 1 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


NOTE: The execution of this query involves performing one or more Cartesian product joins that
      can not be optimized.
NOTE: Table WORK._NAMES has been dropped.
NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds


394  %put %strataed_vars (data=have, var=YAS YES YCS SEP);
YAS0 YES0 YCS0 SEP0 YAS1 YES1 YCS1 SEP1 YAS3 YES3 YCS3 SEP3   <----------------
395
```